# Is this a genuine contradiction?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

On solving a problem I came across the last day, this is what has happened:

Problem:

> Let A(–1, 0) and B(2, 0) be two points on the x-axis. A point 'M' is moving in xy-plane (other than x-axis) in such a way that angle MBA = 2 times angle MAB, then the point 'M' moves along a conic. Find the conic.

My solution:

> Consider the given data that angle MBA is twice angle MAB. Using sine rule in order to get a relation between the distances MA and MB, we eventually get a circle.

(Sorry for the inconvinience of not being able to provide a diagram.)

The given solution:

[image]

Both the methods seem right in their own way, but the final answers are completely different. How can this be explained?

Comment: If you would post your solution, maybe one could find  a mistake

Comment: Consider: Let $B$ be the center of a circle, and $A$ a point on it, and $A^\prime$ the point opposite $A$. Then, the Inscribed Angle Theorem provides that, for points $M$ on the circle, $\angle MBA^\prime = 2\angle MAB$. Note that $\angle MBA^\prime$ in this scenario is the *supplement* of $\angle MBA$ in the problem; the fact these angles have the same sine may be the crux of your error.

Comment: @Andrei, According to the sine rule, since angle MBA is twice angle MAB, MA is twice MB. And using distance formula you get the locus as a circle.

Comment: @Blue, there is no evidence for the assumption that M lies on that circle that you have constructed.

Comment: @AaronJohnSabu: What I'm saying is that the locus *is* a circle if/when you accidentally mistake $\angle MBA$ for its supplement in the problem statement.

Comment: @AaronJohnSabu: BTW, the Law of Sines most certainly **does not** imply that $MA$ is twice $MB$. So, perhaps your error is more egregious than simply mistaking an angle for its supplement. (As Andrei has suggested, showing your solution would help us diagnose the problem.)

Comment: Why doesn't the law of sines 'certainly' not imply that? After all it is the direct meaning of the law right?

Comment: @AaronJohnSabu: Consider the $30^\circ$-$60^\circ$-$90^\circ$ triangle. The leg opposite the $60^\circ$ angle is **not** twice as long as the leg opposite the $30^\circ$ angle.

Comment: Oh thanks. Never noticed that. Another one of my silly mistakes. Good of you

Comment: I mean I considered the sine of the angle as two times instead of the angle itself as two times. That was my mistake.

Comment: @AaronJohnSabu: You should post your realization as an answer (which you can eventually accept), so that the StackExchange system doesn't bump this question to the top of the Unanswered queue in the future.